# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT error when post a form in ajax to spring

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-boot

I use spring boot 2

I try to post in ajax a form.
There a list of string in the form.

```
var form = $('#factoriesForm').serialize();
form = JSON.stringify(form);

$ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "/template/edit/factories/" + factoriesId,
     data: form,
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType : "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#factoriesForm input[name="id"]').val(data.id);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     }
});
```

Server side

```
@PostMapping("template/edit/factories/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public FactoriesDto edit(Model model, @RequestBody FactoriesDto dto, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    return factoriesFacace.save(dto);
}
```

Dto

```
public class FactoriesDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Integer citiesId;
    private String citiesName;
    private List<Integer> machinesId = new ArrayList<>();
    private Collection<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean generatedEmail;
    private boolean generation;
    private String phone;
    private String fax;
    private String director;

    public FactoriesDto() {
    }
    //get set
}
```

Error I get

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String`
>   out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
>   through reference chain: com.lcm.dto.FactoriesDto["emails"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: Are you sure that `emails` is an array in the form? From the error message it seems that possibly an object is being sent instead. Perhaps try debugging by logging the value of `form` before calling `$ajax`.

Comment: Your email field must be sent as `"["email1","email2"]"` instead of `["email1","email2"]`. Debug the form data before sending the request.
Also, do implement `Serializable` interface in `FactoriesDto` class